# how to launch inappbrowser when a webpage is loaded in webview

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am launching a web page in worklight 6.2 container (for android and ios) by clicking a button on index.html page. In my web page I have used `window.open(url,"_blank","location=yes")` to launch an external website in inappbrowser, however it launches in the webview instead of inappbrowser. I assume this is happening because I am loosing cordova plugins when ever the webpage is loaded in my webview. When I write `window.open(url,"_blank","location=yes")` I am able to launch external url in inappbrowser. Is there any way to have same behavior of launching the inappbrowser from a webpage in cordova/worklight webview.

Answer (score 0):

```
_self:  Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
_blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
_system: Opens in the system's web browser.
```

use self instead of blank

Comment: @Imran- Everytime I want to open it in InAppBrowser, thats why I used _blank. Just to give more information the webpage launching in webview is not worklight web application it is just simple jquery-mobile, bootstrap application. I don't see any cordova related files in the webpage. Only thing is my webview or container is generated using worklight. I am not sure whether the inappbrowser feature will be available with the webview even after launching some other webpage which is not having any cordova related files. Let me know if you need more information on this. Thanks.